Spring Shell with docker-compose does not work
I have Spring boot application with Spring shell console. When i running it on a local machine frome IDE everything is good. O wrote Dockerfile and docker-compose to deploy my app, but when i running docker-compose up i don't see Spring shell input. Only after stopping the container this input appears in console.
If there any solutions to use this shell console properly?
Here is my Dockerfile:
FROM openjdk:19 as build
WORKDIR application
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} application.jar
RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar application.jar extract
FROM openjdk:19
WORKDIR application
COPY --from=build application/dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=build application/spring-boot-loader/ ./
COPY --from=build application/snapshot-dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=build application/application/ ./

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher"]

And docker-compose as well:
version: '3.7'
services:
  artemis-viewer:
    image: image:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    ports:
      - "8071:8071"
    environment:
      SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME: "artemis-viewer"
    networks:
      backend:
        aliases:
          - "artemis-viewer"

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge

I also tried to add: stdin_open: true and tty: true, but it does not work

Am I to understand this shell program asks for user input?

Yeap, asks input using shell>

Then it makes little sense to run it in a docker container. Because it'll start listening for input on the shell INSIDE that container

This seems like a more specific case of docker-compose up and user inputs on stdin; Compose doesn't really support running interactive console applications this way.  (What would happen if you had multiple services that both expected to read from stdin?)
